# Cannot read NAS drives formatted for Linux

Tags: linux, raid-1

I have two hard drives (mirrored) in a [QNAP TS-209 Pro II](http://www.qnap.com/en/index.php?sn=822&c=1655&sc=1656&t=1659&n=6681) NAS box that won't mount properly. 
They are formatted for Linux (EXT3 file system) and the problem appears to be with the NAS, not the drives (I could be wrong). Under the NAS, they do not exist. Under my Ubuntu machine, they show up but they can't be mounted. Under Windows, I used to be able to moun,t read, and save files, but now I am back to square one. They won't let me even view their contents (though I can  see how much storage they have left).

None of this makes sense to me, it seems like the drives have minds of their own. Any help would be appreciated, or clarifying questions. Sorry if I am being unclear.

Comment: Which NAS? Which OS runs on the NAS (I am assume some Linux version). Does that include the correct drivers for the way the drives are formatted?

Comment: QNAP TS-209 Pro II. It is a small version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Also, it will recognize and use a new drive if I attach one.

Comment: Can you pull the new drive (the one the NAS recognised) and connect it to a PC? Then check how it is formatted? (e.g. any special partitions with NAS data at the start of the drive? Some NAS's do add their own partitions).

Comment: Yeah, already did. There are 2 EXT3 partitions, one SWAP, and one EXT2. Partition type is Linux (except for the swap, it's a linux swap of course). The first partition should have special NAS data on it, but I can't verify that until a computer can actually read it, somehow.